# Infinite loop while traversing through linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

Deleting and viewing entire queue causes the problem- I'm assuming it is an infinite loop case for traversing. It works perfectly fine for adding the element but execution stops right after 2 or 3 are selected by the user.

I'm just adding some lines of random text before the code because stack isn't allowing such a big code with a small explanation.

Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class linkedlist
{
    struct node
    {
        int number;
        node *next;
    }*HEAD;
public:

    void addelement(int num);
    void exitelement();
    void displayqueue();

};

void linkedlist::addelement(int num)
{
    node *t;
    t= new node;
    t -> number=num;
    t -> next=HEAD;
    HEAD=t;
    cout<<num<<"has successfully been added to the queue /n";
}

void linkedlist::exitelement()
{
    node *t;
    t=HEAD;
    while(t -> next !=NULL)
    {
        t=t -> next;
    }
    cout<<t->number;
    delete t;
}

void linkedlist::displayqueue()
{
    node *t;
    t=HEAD;
    while(t->next !=NULL)
    {
        cout<<t -> number<<"\t";
        t=t->next;
    }
    cout<<" \n that's the end of the list \n";
}

int main()
{
    int lol;
    linkedlist m;
    int rpt=1;
    while(rpt==1)
    {
        int c;
        cout<<"\n please select 1 to add an element, 2 to remove an element from the queue and 3 to display the entire queue \n";
        cin>>c;
        cout<<"/n";
        if(c==1)
        {
            cout<<"enter the number: ";
            cin>>lol;
            m.addelement(lol);
        }
        else if(c==2)
        {
            m.exitelement();
        }
        else if(c==3)
        {
            m.displayqueue();
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"you have entered an invalid input. Sorry \n";
        }
        cout<<"\n Do you wish to start the queue again??? \n";
        cin>>rpt;
    }

}
```

Comment: _"I'm just adding some lines of random text before the code because stack isn't allowing such a big code with a small explanation."_ - Please don't. Those restrictions are there for a purpose. You could - for example - explain what your program is supposed to do, so we don't have to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of problems with the way you attempt to iterate over your list in both `linkedlist::exitelement()` and `linkedlist::displayqueue()`. But before we look at specifics, when you use the *arrow-operator* (`->`) ***there is no space on either side***. Meaning you would do `t->next = HEAD;` NOT `t -> next = HEAD;` (the space on either side of the `'='` is optional -- but encouraged for readability). You also need to ensure your `HEAD` pointer declared in your class is initialized to `nullptr` either by direct initialization or providing a constructor. For now, this will do:

```
class linkedlist
{
    struct node {
        int number;
        node *next;
    } *HEAD = nullptr;
    ...
```

Your `linkedlist::addelement(int num)` function is fine, it uses a method called *forward-chaining* to add nodes at the beginning of the list with each addition. The only caveat is your list ends up in reverse order of the input (which is wanted in some cases, but not in others)

Your `linkedlist::exitelement()` is not functional as it doesn't provide a method of setting the `prev->next` pointer to `nullptr` before removing the current node. The easy way to handle this is by using the address of the current and last nodes as well as a pointer to the current node as you iterate to the end of your list. See [Linus on Understand Pointers](https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/). In approaching list iteration in this manner, you eliminate having to check for any special conditions.

(here the check on `if (HEAD == nullptr)` is only needed to print the `"(queue-empty)"` message in case you try to delete a node from an empty list and prevent dereferencing a `nullptr` for your `cout` of the number at the node to be deleted in that case).

The benefit of using the address-of-the-pointer is that does not change in memory. (you can change or delete what is stored there, but the address itself doesn't change) By keeping track of the addresses with a `node **` pointer (instead of the pointer itself `node*`), you simply iterate to the end of your list with your pointer, (it will be `nullptr` at the end) and then `delete` what is stored at the final address before setting the memory at that location to `nullptr`. (you MUST set the `->next` pointer for the node in your list before the one you delete to `nullptr` when you delete the last node or you will not know where the end of your list is after the `delete`) For example:

```
void linkedlist::exitelement()
{
    if (HEAD == nullptr) {
        cout << "(queue-empty)\n";
        return;
    }

    node **ppt = &HEAD,     /* address of HEAD */
        **last = ppt;       /* address of last (initialized to HEAD) */
    node *pt = HEAD;        /* pointer to node */

    while (pt != nullptr) { /* loop over each node */
        last = ppt;         /* set last to address of previous */
        ppt = &pt->next;    /* set address of current to next */
        pt = pt->next;      /* set current to next */
    }

    cout << (*last)->number << '\n';

    delete *last;           /* delete node at address of last */
    *last = NULL;           /* set memory at last address to nullptr */
}
```

(**note:** above the iteration over the list occurs `while (pt != nullptr)` not `while (pt->next != nullptr)` -- the same is true for your `linkedlist::displayqueue()` below)

There is no need to track the addresses of the pointers when iterating a list simply to print the values at each node. You just use a simply pointer and check if the node is `nullptr`, and if it isn't, print the `number` for the node, advance the pointer and repeat, e.g.

```
void linkedlist::displayqueue()
{
    if (!HEAD) {
        cout << "queue-empty\n";
        return;
    }

    node *t = HEAD;
    while (t != nullptr) {
        cout << t->number << "\t";
        t = t->next;
    }
    cout << "\n(end of the list)\n";
}
```

The remainder of your problems are your failure to ***validate EVERY input*** and failure to empty `stdin` in the event of an input failure. It is imperative, at minimum, you do both. Your program output made it almost impossible to follow what your code was asking for. Your menu being all on one line was difficult to read. The *newline* character is represented by `'\n'` NOT `'/n'` (which is nothing but a forward-slash and a literal `'n'` character).

Cleaning up your menu and the *newline* problem, you menu now displays as:

```
please select:

  1 to add an element
  2 to remove an element
  3 to display the entire queue

choice:
```

Instead of in a single jumbled line. To put the improvements altogether, you can do something similar to the following:

```
int main (void)
{
    int lol;
    linkedlist m {};
    int rpt = 1;

    m.addelement(10);    /* queue elements 10, 20, 30 added for testing to avoid */
    m.addelement(20);    /* having to navigate the menu and input multiple times */
    m.addelement(30);    /* (remove when you are done testing) */

    while (rpt == 1)
    {
        int c;
        cout << "\nplease select:\n\n"
                "  1 to add an element\n"
                "  2 to remove an element\n"
                "  3 to display the entire queue\n\n"
                "choice: ";

        if (!(cin >> c)) {  /* validate EVERY input */
            cerr << "error: invalid integer - choice.\n";
            std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            continue;
        }

        if (c == 1) {
            cout << "enter the number: ";
            if (cin >> lol)
                m.addelement(lol);
            else {
                cerr << "error: invalid integer input.\n";
                std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            }
        }
        else if (c == 2) {
            m.exitelement();
        }
        else if (c == 3) {
            m.displayqueue();
        }
        else {
            cout << "you have entered an invalid input. Sorry \n";
        }
        cout << "\nDo you wish to start the queue again? (0-no, 1-yes): ";
        if (!(cin >> rpt)) {
            cerr << "error: invalid integer input.\n";
            std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    }
}
```

**Test Your Menu and List Separately**

Meaning, the cumbersome nature of your menu makes it difficult to test your list operations due to having to repeatedly enter menu choice and continue input to add and remove nodes. Instead, think about how you can make testing your algorithms easier (separate and apart from your user-interface). For example, here, you can add a simple `is_empty()` member function to report when your list is empty. This will allow you to repeatedly call `m.exitelement();` until it is empty without having to enter anything.

You can add an `is_empty()` member function as simply as:

```
    ...
  public:

    void addelement(int num);
    void exitelement();
    void displayqueue();
    bool is_empty() { return HEAD == nullptr; }
    ...
```

Now to test your list remove your menu entirely and you can reduce your list-test code to something like the following:

```
int main (void)
{
    linkedlist m {};

    for (int i = 1; i < 40; i++)
        m.addelement(i);

    m.displayqueue();

    do
        m.exitelement();
    while (!m.is_empty());
    m.exitelement();        /* just to validate it works as intended */
}
```

(makes testing your list a whole lot easier `:)`

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

In your addelement() method, whenever you are adding a new node, you are always putting

```
t -> next=HEAD;
```

**Hence for all your nodes, the next will never be null**. Hence the display and exiteElement functions will always fall in infinity loop.

Other than that, your whole linkedlist implementation has some other problems, which need to be fixed if you want any functionality to work correctly. You can take a look at this [link](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL2_aWCzGMAwI3W_JlcBbtYTwiQSsOTa6P) for better understanding.

Comment: `t->next = HEAD;` is fine as the next statement `HEAD = t;` reassigns the head node in a method called *Forward-Chaining*. (all elements are being added to the front of the list)